# Ajax call and windows authentication not working correct

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I have a asp.met mvc 4 project.

This is my view code, minimized:

```
@model E4.administrasjon.Models.ViewModels.vmRekv
<form action="#" method="post" class="form label-inline" id="saveTask">
 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.rekv.RekvID)
<div class="field"><label for="Subject">Titel</label><input id="Subject" value="@Model.rekv.Subject" name="Subject" size="50" type="text" class="medium" /></div>
```

I then have this javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnSave').click(function () {
        alert("clicked");
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:88/API/apiRekv',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $('form#saveTask').serialize(),
            success: function (data) {                        
                alert("OK");                   
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("Error");                    
            }
        });      
    });
});
```

The controller is a simple WebApi controller

```
public void Post(vmRekv item)
    {           
        //Some insert to db code
}
```

The insert operation work with both anonymous and Windows authentication turned on/off. But when I turn on Windows auth. then the javascript success/failure event are not called.

Its called as it should when windows authentication turned off.

By the way, I'm using local IIS express

Answer (score 0):

Try using jsonp. or adding a callback at the end of your url.
localhost:88/API/apiRekv?callback=?

Comment: I dont understand using callback. When looking at Fiddler it looks like its already calling back to the controller.

Comment: I don't think fiddler understands where your localhost is.

Comment: Ok. I get the data in fiddler going agains localhost.. also the JSON calls. I'll see if this makes any difference if I publish the code to a regular IIS server

Comment: Using regular IIS was not different from IIS express. I could have a look at jsonp as Rob sugested, but would really like to make the code that I have work.